# Cannot build main.jsbundle file either manually or automatically

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, node-modules

I am trying to buil the /ios/main.jsbundle file manually in the command line (MacOSX Mojave 10.14.4 (18E226)) having ./index.js as entry file. But I don't succeed.

Then I use this file in Xcode (Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)).

I am building main.jsbundle with the following commands from the root folder:

```
$ react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output main.jsbundle
```

OR

```
$ react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform its --bundle-output main.jsbundle
```

this appears with the --verbose flag:

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
error index.js: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/me/MyApp/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support.js
debug Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/me/MyApp/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support.js
    at createDescriptor (/Users/me/MyApp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
    at /Users/me/MyApp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/me/MyApp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/me/MyApp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at presets (/Users/me/MyApp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
    at mergeChainOpts (/Users/me/MyApp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
    at /Users/me/MyApp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7
    at mergeExtendsChain (/Users/me/MyApp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:299:21)
```

I tried to find a similar question, but nothing.

I have also tried to clean the cache, clear watchman watches, killing the metro bundler, relaunch Xcode, update brew, npm.

These are my files:

- package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.77.0",
    "flow-remove-types": "^1.2.3",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "flow-remove-types --all --pretty ./flow_src/ -d ./src",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test/config/setup.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/test/config/setup",
      "/test/config/assetsTransformer"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/test/config/assetsTransformer.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/test/config/assetsTransformer.js"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.17",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.53",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.0.7",
    "assert": "^1.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "braces": "^2.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.59.8",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-doc-viewer": "^2.7.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.13.3",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-pdf": "^3.0.17",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^4.4.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native-timeago": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^3.2.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.3",
    "yallist": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

*.babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- System Info

```
info 
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.4
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
      Memory: 20.87 GB / 32.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.1.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 10.2.1/10E1001 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: ^16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
      react-native: ^0.59.8 => 0.59.8 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```